# Help understanding basic algebra step in the proof for the differential equation for movement in a simple pendulum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't follow the second to last step in the proof, which can be found on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Simple_gravity_pendulum) in the `"Energy" derivation of (Eq. 1)` table. The proof is a rather simple one, at least I can follow the rest of the proof quite easily.

The specific step is going from

\begin{align*}
    \dot{\theta} &= \frac{\sqrt{2g \cdot h}}{l}\\
    h            &= l \cdot (\cos \theta - \cos \theta_0)                      
\end{align*}

to

\begin{align*}
    \dot{\theta} &= \sqrt{\frac{2g}{l} (\cos \theta - \cos \theta_0)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dot{\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{2gh}}{l} = \sqrt{\frac{2gh}{l^2}}$$
Now you insert $h = l \cdot (cos \theta - cos \theta_0)$ and you get
$$\dot{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{2g}{l^2} l (\cos \theta - \cos \theta_0)} = \sqrt{\frac{2g}{l} (cos \theta - cos \theta_0)}$$

Comment: Oh, that was surprisingly obvious. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the small green checkmark.

Comment: I thought it was generally accepted to wait a while, to give others a time to answer. StackExchange tells me i can accept it in 2 minutes